# Redirect on Ajax Jquery Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am newbie to ajax here and I know somebody would have encountered this problem already.
I have a legacy app built on Spring MVC, it has a interceptor(filter) that redirects the user to the login
page whenever there is no session.

```
public class SessionCheckerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
  HttpSession session = request.getSession();

  // check if userInfo exist in session
  User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
  if (user == null) {
   response.sendRedirect("login.htm");
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
}
```

For non-xmlhttp request, this works fine.. but when I try to use ajax in my application, everything gets weird,
it is not able to redirect to the login page correctly.
As check the value of the

xhr.status = 200  textStatus = parseError  errorThrown = "Invalid JSON -Markup of my HTML Login Page-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "populateData.htm",
            dataType:"json",
            data:"userId=SampleUser",
            success:function(response){
             //code here
            },
         error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status);
             }

        });
});
```

I checked on my firebug that there is a 302 HTTP response but I am not sure how to catch the response and redirect the user to the login
page.  Any idea here?  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

JQuery is looking for a *json* type result, but because the redirect is processed automatically, it will receive the *generated html source* of your `login.htm` page.

One idea is to let the the browser know that it should redirect by adding a `redirect` variable to to the resulting object and checking for it in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: "populateData.htm", 
        dataType:"json", 
        data:"userId=SampleUser", 
        success:function(response){ 
            if (response.redirect) {
                window.location.href = response.redirect;
            }
            else {
                // Process the expected results...
            }
        }, 
     error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status); 
         } 

    }); 
});
```

You could also add a Header Variable to your response and let your browser decide where to redirect. In Java, instead of redirecting, do `response.setHeader("REQUIRES_AUTH", "1")` and in JQuery you do on success(!):

```
//....
        success:function(response){ 
            if (response.getResponseHeader('REQUIRES_AUTH') === '1'){ 
                window.location.href = 'login.htm'; 
            }
            else {
                // Process the expected results...
            }
        }
//....
```

Hope that helps.

My answer is heavily inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call) which shouldn't left any questions in case you still have some problems.

Comment: Hi moonground.. Thanks, I think I got your point already given this example...  Thank you very much...

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I kinda get it but I am going to read your referenced thread some more so it can sink in a bit. Nonetheless, it appears to be the answer I'm looking for so thanks a million for that!

Comment: How can I add redirect variable to response?

Answer (score 2):

For ExpressJs router:

```js
router.post('/login', async(req, res) => {
    return res.send({redirect: '/yoururl'});
})
```

Client-side:

```js
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.redirect) {
            window.location = response.redirect
        }
    },
```