# send pdf to browser after ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a php script that gets called via an ajax call. Values are sent to this script to build a pdf. I want to send the pdf to the browser, but since the script that builds the pdf returns to the page with the javascript I can't see how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend something a bit different. Instead of AJAX call make a redirect to an URL like this:

```
./path_to_pdf_script/script.php?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

This script would be the one which generated the pdf. Place somewhere on top of the script this header:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

And simply `echo` the string the pdf content is in. If you want the user to download this pdf instead of viewing you could do the AJAX call with the example found [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> **from php.net**
>
> If you want the user to be prompted to save the data you are sending,
>   such as a generated PDF file, you can use the » Content-Disposition
>   header to supply a recommended filename and force the browser to
>   display the save dialog.
>
> ```
> <?php
> // We'll be outputting a PDF
> header('Content-type: application/pdf');
>
> // It will be called downloaded.pdf
> header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
>
> // The PDF source is in original.pdf
> readfile('original.pdf');
> ?>
> ```

Comment: All this is the usual way to send a pdf file, and I reckon it can be a prefered way to handle the problem, but it doesn't answer the question. If the PDF is generated through AJAX, in the background of the web page, then how to send the file only when it is ready?

Comment: yeah, your right, for that maybe some temporal file's would do the trick, ajax call goes to pdf generator, which generates the pdf and saves it to a temporal file, save the pdf filename to session, send ok back to client, and from there redirect to a pdf-server script which get's filename from session, reads it, serves it and deletes it

Answer (score 2):

You could use an iframe instead of an ajax request and force-download the pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, your AJAX call can't directly output the PDF to the browser. One workaround is to remove AJAX and send the user directly to the page that generates the PDF. This approach is very common and well documented. But there is a way to use AJAX to generate the PDF, so that the user will stay on the web page until the file is ready.

Your AJAX call could answer with a JSON object with 2 exclusive fields:

- "pdfurl" if the pdf file was successfully created and written to the disk,
- "errormsg" if there was an error.

Something like (in PHP):

```
<?php
//...
if (writepdf($filename, ...)) {
    $result = array('pdfurl' => '/files/' . $filename);
} else {
    $result = array('errormsg' => 'Error!');
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Then the page's javascript could contain (jQuery example):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "ajaxcreatepdf.php",
    data: {userid: 1},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        if (data.pdfurl) {
            window.location.href = data.pdfurl;
        }
        else {
            $("#messagebox").html(data.errormsg);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax request is not direct visible to the user, so a redirect make no sense

You need to load this PDF into an existing or new browser window after the ajax has returned.

Comment: Have you tried sending a redirect header in AJAX call? If I recall right it will redirect the browser, even tho it's just AJAX

Comment: No, because I considered this as weird. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927044/redirect-on-ajax-jquery-call ajax-redirect needs to be programmed

Comment: Consider you have running two Ajax-call. Both do a redirect. Who should win?