# Read and send a file to the browser and then delete

Tags: php, pdf, download

### My Question

I have a script that generates a PDF as a 'one-off'. My script then reads the file and sends it to the browser.

The problem that I have is that I need to delete the file once it has been successfully sent to the browser.

I know that there can be issues with detecting whether or not the user has completely downloaded the file, this being the reason why I am asking this question...

Is there a reliable way to send a file to the browser, and then delete it once it has been fully sent/downloaded to the clients browser/computer?

### My Research

I have searched around a lot and can see that this may not be possible. The following questions offered a little information on the topic:

1. [send pdf to browser after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859738/send-pdf-to-browser-after-ajax-call)
2. [deleting a file after user download it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641667/deleting-a-file-after-user-download-it)

Both these questions seem to contradict each other with one saying you can do it if you use `ignore_user_abort` etc, and the other saying that it cannot be done...

**I am aware that another potential solution is to simply run a cronjob/scheduled task to delete any files that are over X mins old... I will resort to this as my last option**

### What I have tried

So far, I have played around with a few things but nothing yet has worked... My code as it stands looks like this:

```
// Set the headers to PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// Read the file and send it to the browser
readfile($this->paths['WWW'].'/test.pdf');

// Delete the file
unlink($this->paths['WWW'].'/test.pdf');
```

### UPDATE

I have just re-tested my code and it appears to be working just fine... There was a permissions error on the file so it wasnt deleting when I called `unlink`.

However, I am still a little cautious about using this method. Can I be sure that the file will be delivered and then deleted after it has been sent?

***I have tested this with a large PDF file and it does work so the above solution may actually be correct. I would still appreciate any other thoughts if anybody wishes to share or can see any hidden issues with this method.***

Comment: Just generate the PDF and send it to the user. Don't save it as a file in the first place.

Comment: @Quentin Sadly I am using a COM to generate the PDF so it has to create it...

Answer (score 0):

This might be a silly thing. But most PDF Gernerating libraries have a stream option.

So you url syntax would be steampdf.php?id=12. This outputs a file names My_Super_Duper_pdf.pdf and that's it.

An Example for TCPDF

```
//Databaselogic goes here 
$db->select_all_records_and_merge_the_pdf();
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 40, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 40);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);

//do pdf logic:
        $tblHeading = '<table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-family: ralewaybold; font-size: 16pt;">Factuur</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: ralewayreg; font-size: 12pt;">x:</td>
                <td style="font-family: ralewayreg; font-size: 12pt;">'.$varInvoiceNumber.'</td>        
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: ralewayreg; font-size: 12pt;">x:</td>
                <td style="font-family: ralewayreg; font-size: 12pt;">'.$varInvoiceDate.'</td>
            </tr>
        </table>';

        $pdf->writeHTMLCell(100, 40, 20, 100.5, $tblHeading);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

return $pdf->Output("My_Super_Duper_pdf.pdf","S");
```